# parquet with different schema

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a list of parquet files in my folder `./my_file/*.parquet`.
The good ones have a column "date_time" which is supposed to be an integer (unix epoch timestamp).

```
root
 |-- date_time: integer (nullable = true)
```

But some of them have instead a real timestamp field.

```
root
 |-- date_time: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

The problem is that all these files are in the same folder and when I read them, any `action` on my dataframe generate an error :

> Column: [date_time], Expected: LongType, Found: INT96

Do you have any good method so I can separate easily the "timestamp" files from the "integer" files ? 
I have over 30k files in my folder and I just do not know how I can process them because any action generates an error.